# My work VPN suddenly started failing to connect silently

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn

I used to be able to connect to my work VPN, but as of yesterday, it just silently fails to connect. I'm using the Windows 10 built-in VPN software in the Settings app, and when I try to connect, I briefly see the message "Connecting to (name of VPN)", and then it disappears and I'm disconnected with no error message or anything like that. What might be causing this? I'm running Windows 10 Home 64-bit, and I don't know what OS the server I'm trying to connect to is running. Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried contacting your work IT team?

Comment: Don't really have one, it's a small business.. Told my boss, the business owner, about the issue and he's kind of busy this week what with the holiday, so I thought I'd ask around.

Comment: Look in the Windows event log and gather up the info about the failure and add that info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I should have known, this is Windows - rebooting fixes everything!